# How to add a 'title' to a UIBarButtonItem

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

I understand how to creata UIBarButtonItem with text and make it look like a title. I essentially want one more line of smaller text below that 'explaining' what the big text is.

using initWithCustomView with 2 views seems to get much more complicated because of width.

Comment: Have you ever seen that anywhere? Or you just want to make it for the first time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible solution is to use initWithCustomView method on the UIBarButtonItem and then set the left or rightBarButtonItem property in the UINavigationItem with this bar button.

And to add the obvious, your customView can be the multiline UILabel.